# How was this question answered months before it was asked?

Tags: support, answers, timestamps

I just saw this question asked a few minutes ago: [How can I cause an instruction cache miss?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588567/how-can-i-cause-an-instruction-cache-miss). To my surprise, it already had 6 answers from two months ago. The question has no edit history, the user is new, and there is no message that I can see about anything special happening to the question.

So, what happened?

Comment: I've never noticed that, always check the revision history: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10588567/revisions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answers were merged from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793660/what-are-the-causes-for-instruction-cache-miss) (10k only).

Check out the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10588567/revisions).

Comment: At least for me, that other question link redirects to the new question. And I kind of wonder why this happened

Comment: @murgatroid99: The question gets deleted if its merged into another, only 10k users can view the original. I have no idea why he chose the newer one over the older, but if you saw the original text, the question bodies are virtually the *exact* same.

Comment: @animuson Without going into private details, this had to do with a user request and the desire to preserve the information in the answers.